# QLineEdit mouseEnter() and mouseExit() events

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I want to subclass `QLineEdit` to add it some signals like **`mouseEnter()`** and **`mouseExit()`** to become informed when the mouse courser is over the widget and when leaves it.
I could write **`mouseEnter()`** like below.

```
class MyLineEdit:public QLineEdit{
//
// ..
//
protected: 
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

signals:
    void mouseEnter();
}

void MyLineEdit::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    emit mouseEnter();
    QLineEdit::mouseMoveEvent(e);
}
```

It works correctly.
How can I write **`mouseExit()`**?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#leaveEvent ; http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#enterEvent

Answer (score 2):

leaveEvent is not a very good name!

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QEvent>

class Editor : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void leaveEvent(QEvent *);

signals:
    void mouseLeave();
};

void Editor::leaveEvent(QEvent *e);
{
    qDebug() << "Mouse has left the building..";
    emit mouseLeave();
}
```